# How to correctly destroy window that is running from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety, createwindow

The goal that I am trying to achieve is to listen session notifications about lock, unlock and so on. I have to do it in another thread due to architecture and avoiding blocking main thread. Here is what I am doing:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
        switch (wParam) {
        case WTS_CONSOLE_CONNECT:
        case WTS_SESSION_LOGON:
        case WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT:
        case WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK:
        case WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT:
        case WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT:
        case WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF:
        case WTS_SESSION_LOCK:
        case WTS_SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL:
        case WTS_SESSION_CREATE:
        case WTS_SESSION_TERMINATE:

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void startListeningNotifications()
{
    const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"myWindowClass";

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        return;
    }

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, g_szClassName, L"", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hwnd, NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS))
    {
        return;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);

    MSG Msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread listener(startListeningNotifications);
    listener.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem that I am facing right now is that I do not know how to correctly write stopListeningNotifications() method. I have to somehow destroy my window and quit message loop. Please advice how to do that safely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be aware, that each message loop is running in it's own thread. So simply sending a message to that window won't be a good idea. I'd try using a [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to signal the window it's supposed to close. The receiving window can simply call it's own `Close()` function, if the notificaiton is received.

Comment: `PostMessageW(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)`

Comment: But is this thread safe?

Comment: of course thread safe. what here can be not safe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided `WndProc` function handles `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_DESTROY`.

```
case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
```

So you could send `WM_CLOSE` message with `hwnd` of the window created in the thread:

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Could I send this message in any thread? In my case it will be main thread.

Comment: You can send messages to any thread, even the one that did not create the window ([PostThreadMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagea)), but the target thread must have a message loop.

Comment: I already tried that but that's not working for me. But when I tried this PostMessage() from main thread (without PostThreadMessage) it works.

Comment: Did posting `WM_CLOSE`  solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, but I am posting it from another thread, I do not think this is thread safe.

Comment: Using `PostMessage` with window handle is thread safe.

Comment: [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553)